# What screensaver for Windows can display a console window?

Tags: windows, screensaver

What screensaver for Windows can display a console window, and be used to run a custom console application?

For example, a screensaver that could be configured with the command "ping -t 10.0.0.1". When activated, it blanks the screen and displays a continuous ping to a host. Then when the mouse moves, it terminates the "ping" process.

(That was an example; I'm looking for a general-purpose screensaver that can run *any* console application.)

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 0):

Try Screen Launcher. It can run any application as a screen saver.
http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Screensavers/Screen-Launcher.shtml

Comment: Good thought - but it doesn't blank the screen; nor does it kill the process once I move the mouse.